# Регулярная сеть

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графика, движок

В попытке оптимизации нахождение коллизии(столкновение) блоков был найден способ сортировки методом "[Регулярной сеткой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135948/)" вопрос как с помощью алгоритма "Ограничителя" описать это условие:

Имеется массив блоков(зеленый цвет)
Из этого массива проверяются коллизия блоков находящиеся в кубе ограничителе(желтый цвет)

Проверка идёт между главным кубом(красный цвет) и массивом кубов(зелёный цвет)

Всё что за ограничителем (желтый цвет) не провертывается на столкновение.
[image]

### Регулярная сеть

Как вы, вероятно, уже догадались из названия, суть алгоритма сводится к тому, что все пространство делится на равномерную сеть из маленьких квадратиков, размер которых равен диаметру частицы. Каждый такой квадратик(ячейка) этой сети представляет собой массив.
Выглядеть это может, например, так:

```
const int _GRID_WIDTH = (int)(WIDTH / (RADIUS_P * 2.0f));
const int _GRID_HEIGHT = (int)(HEIGHT / (RADIUS_P * 2.0f));

std::vector<Particle *> _grid[_GRID_WIDTH][_GRID_HEIGHT];
```

На каждой итерации главного цикла эта сеть очищается и заново заполняется. Алгоритм заполнения предельно прост: индекс ячейки частицы вычисляется путем деления обеих координат на диаметр частицы и отбрасыванием дробной части. Пример:

```
int x = (int)(_particles[i].pos.x / (RADIUS_P * 2.0f));
int y = (int)(_particles[i].pos.y / (RADIUS_P * 2.0f));
```

Таким образом, для каждой частицы необходимо вычислить индекс и внести ее в ячейку с этим индексом(добавить элемент в массив).
Теперь остается только пройтись по каждой ячейке и проверить все ее частицы со всеми частицами соседних, окружающих ее 8 ячеек, при этом не забыв проверить с самой собой.

Это можно сделать так:

```
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _GRID_WIDTH; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _GRID_HEIGHT; ++j) {
            _grid[i][j].clear();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_P; ++i) {
        int x = (int)(_particles[i].pos.x / (RADIUS_P * 2.0f));
        int y = (int)(_particles[i].pos.y / (RADIUS_P * 2.0f));

        _grid[x][y].push_back(&_particles[i]);
    }

    // далее много циклов проверки с соседними ячейками
}
```

Сложность: O(n)

Плюсы:
* Самый быстрый из всех

- Прост в реализации

Минусы:

- Требуется дополнительная память
- Чувствителен к разным размерам частиц(требуется модификация)

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Как проверять только блоки внутри желтого куба? Про какие именно условия речь?

Comment: Проверка происходит только в желтом кубе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяй вот это **"Теперь остается только пройтись по каждой ячейке и проверить все ее частицы со всеми частицами соседних, окружающих ее 8 ячеек, при этом не забыв проверить с самой собой."** только для тех "каждых" ячеек которые попадают внутрь желтого куба (или центры которых попадают внутрь желтого куба).

P.S.Зеленые и красные кубы надо поместить в твой Grid, перед проверкой, и как-то запомнить кто зеленый, а кто красный, если нужны коллизии только для кубов разного цвета.